# nohup doesn't work when used with double-ampersand (&&) instead of semicolon (;)

Tags: bash, nohup

I have a script that uses `ssh` to login to a remote machine, `cd` to a particular directory, and then start a daemon. The original script looks like this:

```
ssh server "cd /tmp/path ; nohup java server 0</dev/null 1>server_stdout 2>server_stderr &"
```

This script appears to work fine. However, it is not robust to the case when the user enters the wrong path so the `cd` fails. Because of the `;`, this command will try to run the `nohup` command even if the `cd` fails.

The obvious fix doesn't work:

```
ssh server "cd /tmp/path && nohup java server 0</dev/null 1>server_stdout 2>server_stderr &"
```

that is, the SSH command does not return until the server is stopped. Putting `nohup` in front of the `cd` instead of in front of the `java` didn't work.

Can anyone help me fix this? Can you explain why this solution doesn't work? Thanks!

**Edit:** cbuckley suggests using `sh -c`, from which I derived:

```
ssh server "nohup sh -c 'cd /tmp/path && java server 0</dev/null 1>master_stdout 2>master_stderr' 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null &"
```

However, now the exit code is always `0` when the `cd` fails; whereas if I do `ssh server cd /failed/path` then I get a real exit code. Suggestions?

Comment: You could wrap `nohup` around the whole expression: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47230/how-to-execute-multiple-command-using-nohup

Comment: Thanks! I can't accept a comment, I think. This still seems unnecessarily ugly, and I have no idea why the `&&` breaks things.

Comment: Also, with `sh -c` I don't get the error code when the `cd` fails.

Comment: How about `ssh server "mkdir /tmp/path 2>> /dev/null ; nohup java ..."`. That would attempt to create the directory if it doesn't exist, which would fail if it did, but the failure of `mkdir` is then ignored. There's still the corner case where `/tmp/path` doesn't exist, but `mkdir` also fails because it doesn't have permissions to create it, but that shouldn't be the case as long as you're really dealing with `/tmp/...`.

Comment: Oh, another point to clear up in my question.The `cd` error is when the user runs the wrong command... so we don't want to create the directories. Thanks though!

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to solve. I would think that the chain of `ssh` and `sh -c` are returning 0 because they did  what you asked them without trouble. If you don't want the java to execute after a failed cd, the && should prevent that, are you saying it doesn't? If you want non-zero returns in the shell, you might have to explcitly exit with $? as the last statement in your remote script. You may find that its not really `&&`'s fault and that a full bore error exit gets consumed too. Does `if [  cd $usrPath ] ; then ..... else echo errorMsg; exit 1 ; fi` work? Good luck!

Comment: Right, `sh -c` always returns `0`. E.g., `sh -c exit 1` has error code `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Bash's Operator Precedence](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/opprecedence.html).

The `&` is being attached to the whole statement because it has a higher precedence than `&&`.  You don't need `ssh` to verify this.  Just run this in your shell:

```
$ sleep 100 && echo yay &
[1] 19934
```

If the `&` were only attached to the `echo yay`, then your shell would sleep for 100 seconds and *then* report the background job.  However, the entire `sleep 100 && echo yay` is backgrounded and you're given the job notification immediately.  Running `jobs` will show it hanging out:

```
$ sleep 100 && echo yay &
[1] 20124
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 100 && echo yay &
```

You can use parenthesis to create a subshell around `echo yay &`, giving you what you'd expect:

```
sleep 100 && ( echo yay & )
```

This would be similar to using `bash -c` to run `echo yay &`:

```
sleep 100 && bash -c "echo yay &"
```

Tossing these into an `ssh`, and we get:

```
# using parenthesis...
$ ssh localhost "cd / && (nohup sleep 100 >/dev/null </dev/null &)"
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
me 20136     1  0 16:48 ?        00:00:00 sleep 100

# and using `bash -c`
$ ssh localhost "cd / && bash -c 'nohup sleep 100 >/dev/null </dev/null &'"
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
me 20145     1  0 16:48 ?        00:00:00 sleep 100
```

Applying this to your command, and we get

```
ssh server "cd /tmp/path && (nohup java server 0</dev/null 1>server_stdout 2>server_stderr &)"
```

or:

```
ssh server "cd /tmp/path && bash -c 'nohup java server 0</dev/null 1>server_stdout 2>server_stderr &'"
```

Also, with regard to your comment on the post,

> Right, `sh -c` always returns 0. E.g., `sh -c exit 1` has error code
>   0"

this is incorrect.  Directly from the manpage:

> Bash's exit status is the exit status of the last command executed in
>   the script.  If no commands are  executed,  the exit status is 0.

Indeed:

```
$ bash -c "true ; exit 1"
$ echo $?
1
$ bash -c "false ; exit 22"
$ echo $?
22
```

Comment: If you just want to override precedence, you can use `{ cmd ; }` instead of creating a subshell.

Answer (score 1):

ssh server "test -d /tmp/path" && ssh server "nohup ... &"

Answer (score 0):

Answer roundup:

- Bad: Using `sh -c` to wrap the entire `nohup` command doesn't work for my purposes because it doesn't return error codes. (@cbuckley)
- Okay: `ssh <server> <cmd1> && ssh <server> <cmd2>` works but is much slower (@joachim-nilsson)
- Good: Create a shell script on `<server>` that runs the commands in succession and returns the correct error code.

The last is what I ended up using. I'd still be interested in learning why the original use-case doesn't work, if someone who understands shell internals can explain it to me!